# cmake approach to cpp project split into src and include

Tags: c++, cmake

I am having trouble understanding what I have to read from cmake documentation in order to write a `CMakeLists.txt` for this directory structure (the `main` is `solver_fullyParallelized_shtns_3D.cpp`):

```
$ tree
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── GPS_global_vars.hpp
│   ├── absorber_fns.hpp
│   ├── distribution_fns.hpp
│   ├── laser_field.hpp
│   ├── matrix_transposition_fns.hpp
│   ├── matrix_vector_prods_for_propagation.hpp
│   ├── shtns_transforms_fns.hpp
│   ├── utility_fns_C_CPP.hpp
│   └── utility_fns_GPS.hpp
└── src
    ├── absorber_fns.cpp
    ├── distribution_fns.cpp
    ├── laser_field.cpp
    ├── matrix_transposition_fns.cpp
    ├── matrix_vector_prods_for_propagation.cpp
    ├── shtns_transforms_fns.cpp
    ├── solver_fullyParallelized_shtns_3D.cpp
    ├── utility_fns_C_CPP.cpp
    └── utility_fns_GPS.cpp

2 directories, 19 files
```

Each `.cpp` file from `src/` can (some of them do, some of them don't) have at its beginning:

```
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
```

I can ''locate'' this external library as:

```
# xtensor
target_include_directories(TDSE_solver PUBLIC "/work/e281/e281/ouatu_i/trial_Carrays_IntelMKL_Xtensor_SHTNS_CrayFFTW/xtensor_all/xtensor_install_dir/include/")
target_include_directories(TDSE_solver PUBLIC "/work/e281/e281/ouatu_i/trial_Carrays_IntelMKL_Xtensor_SHTNS_CrayFFTW/xtensor_all/xtl_install_dir/include/")
target_include_directories(TDSE_solver PUBLIC "/work/e281/e281/ouatu_i/TDSE_3D_Telnov/xtensor_io_install/include/")
```

But do I have to do it for every .cpp I have?

That is, the below complete CMakeLists.txt fails:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(TDSE_solver)

# For ARCHER2:
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "cc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "CC")

# For inline variables in CPP
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -O3 -pedantic -Wshadow")

# OpenMP
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES
src/absorber_fns.cpp
src/distribution_fns.cpp
src/laser_field.cpp
src/matrix_transposition_fns.cpp
src/matrix_vector_prods_for_propagation.cpp
src/shtns_transforms_fns.cpp
src/solver_fullyParallelized_shtns_3D.cpp
src/utility_fns_C_CPP.cpp
src/utility_fns_GPS.cpp)

add_executable(TDSE_solver src/solver_fullyParallelized_shtns_3D.cpp)
target_include_directories(TDSE_solver PUBLIC include)


# xtensor
target_include_directories(TDSE_solver PUBLIC "/work/e281/e281/ouatu_i/trial_Carrays_IntelMKL_Xtensor_SHTNS_CrayFFTW/xtensor_all/xtensor_install_dir/include/")
target_include_directories(TDSE_solver PUBLIC "/work/e281/e281/ouatu_i/trial_Carrays_IntelMKL_Xtensor_SHTNS_CrayFFTW/xtensor_all/xtl_install_dir/include/")
target_include_directories(TDSE_solver PUBLIC "/work/e281/e281/ouatu_i/TDSE_3D_Telnov/xtensor_io_install/include/")

add_library(absorber_fns STATIC src/absorber_fns.cpp)
add_library(distribution_fns STATIC src/distribution_fns.cpp)
add_library(laser_field STATIC src/laser_field.cpp)
add_library(matrix_transposition_fns STATIC src/matrix_transposition_fns.cpp)
add_library(matrix_vector_prods_for_propagation STATIC src/matrix_vector_prods_for_propagation.cpp)
add_library(shtns_transforms_fns STATIC src/shtns_transforms_fns.cpp)
add_library(utility_fns_C_CPP STATIC src/utility_fns_C_CPP.cpp)
add_library(utility_fns_GPS STATIC src/utility_fns_GPS.cpp)

if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
target_link_libraries(
TDSE_solver 
PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX
absorber_fns 
distribution_fns 
laser_field 
matrix_transposition_fns 
matrix_vector_prods_for_propagation
shtns_transforms_fns
utility_fns_C_CPP
utility_fns_GPS)
endif()
```

With the error:

```
distribution_fns.cpp:7:10: fatal error: xtensor/xarray.hpp: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
```

Do I confuse / make things wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What was your motivation for defining a separate library for every .cpp file? Why not just `add_executable(TDSE_solver src/solver_fullyParallelized_shtns_3D.cpp ${SOURCES})`?

Comment: @Botje, I have to acknowledge there is no real motivation behind that. By following the online cmake tutorial from their website, I thought that's what one needs to do. I will try what you say now. Thanks

Comment: You generally only need to declare a library if you want to share code between different targets in your CMake project. (or if your project's goal is to be a library, but well...)

Comment: @Botje, after I did what you said, I observe that I get another errors now, related to my cpp syntax, so totally different. I thus believe you solved the problem I posted in this question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @velenos14 How did you install xtensor? Did you use 'conda' or 'vcpkg' ?

Comment: @spiros, this was a lot of time ago, but I never used any of those commands you mentioned. From source I think. Downloaded with ``$ git clone`` all their repos and then manually installing each part of xtensor (io, xarray, etc). Just for curiosity, why do you ask?

Comment: @velenos14 you need xtensor installed to include it in your c++ headers and cmake file.

Comment: @spiros, sorry, what makes you think it is not installed? I used it in other projects and works fine

Comment: @velenos14 i am trying to understand what is wrong with your code. If you have it installed, you have to add the find xtensor package part. So under the 'find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED) ' line you can try adding :                                                
find_package(xtensor REQUIRED)

Comment: @spiros, I think I see what you mean. I am on a HPC cluster and installed xtensor myself from source in a custom directory created by myself. I use it as a header only library, by including some ``#`` at the top of my cpp files. I make the C++ compiler/linker know about the location of these ```#.h``` by using ```target_include_directories()``` and this worked all the times in other c++ projects which used xtensor and cmake (they only had 1 cpp file, though). the problem from this question was that I didn't know how to handle multiple .cpp files using cmake.